# Limit: $\lim_{n→∞}\frac{(n^5+2)^{1/4}−(n^2+1)^{1/3}} {(n^4+2)^{1/5}−(n^3+1)^{1/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Limit:
$$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{(n^5+2)^{1/4}−(n^2+1)^{1/3}}
{(n^4+2)^{1/5}−(n^3+1)^{1/2}}$$
My guess would be to divide top by $n^5$ and bottom by $n^4$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that dividing the top by one value and the bottom by another value changes the fraction which might result in a different limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the terms in this expansion behave like a power of $n$ for large $n$:

- $(n^5+2)^{1/4}\sim n^{5/4}$
- $(n^2+1)^{1/3}\sim n^{2/3}$
- $(n^4+2)^{1/5}\sim n^{4/5}$
- $(n^3+1)^{1/2}\sim n^{3/2}$

We can justify these by noting that $(n^\alpha+c)^{1/k}=(n^\alpha(1+\frac{c}{n^\alpha}))^{1/k}=n^{\alpha/k}(1+\frac{c}{n^\alpha})^{1/k}\sim n^{\alpha/k}$ for $\alpha>0, n\to\infty$.

As such, the numerator can be seen to be $\sim n^{5/4}$, and the denominator is $\sim-n^{3/2}$. Comparing the exponents, we see that the ratio ought to tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.